# rainerscript: how to log to file named $programname substring?

Tags: scripting, syslog, rsyslog

How can I write a `rainerscript` rule to log to a file whose name is a substring of `$programname`?

I want something along the lines of this pseudo-rule:

```
if $programname startswith "foo" then /path/to/<substring of $programname from 4 to end>
```

Also: is there a way to strip the "foo" prefix from `$programname` in the text that gets written to file?

Comment: I'd like to see this answered as well.

Comment: @TonyG - if you could upvote this question, that will indicate to users that it's more than just one person (me) interested in an answer...and hopefuly a rainerscript expert will be among them. :)

Comment: Actually no, sorry. Upvoting is to praise an author for a well-researched question. That's not what I see. I did a lot of research since yesterday. The answers are in the docs https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable - too many pages to cite here. Also https://www.rsyslog.com/how-to-use-set-variable-and-exec_template/ It's not easy to cogitate an answer from all of the raw information, examples are sparse. You need to carefully read detail on templates, RainerScript, actions. I've written a lot of code today with partial success, so no "Answer" from me yet. Experiment. Improve your question.

Comment: Meh, I don't mean to be grouchy. See my Answer. :)

Comment: @TonyG - no grouchiness inferred; you have a valid assessment of the purpose of upvoting. My question was actually after much research, but it's sometimes hard/pointless to convey "I've been poring through the documentation" in text. So I didn't post the question with the intent "hey, someone else figure this out for me"...it was more like "I've exhausted my ability to derive an answer from the sources I've browsed...perhaps this is a known/easy answer to a knowledgeable U&L user out there".

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm feeling unhelpful with my comment to the OP. I did some more testing and here's a solid answer that I'd like to share:

Create /etc/rsyslog.d/00-local.conf with the following:

```
template(name="AdminLog" type="string" string="/var/log/admin_%syslogtag:R,ERE,1,ZERO::(.*):--end%")

if ($programname == "admin") then {
  action(type="omfile" dynaFile="AdminLog")
  stop
}
```

`systemctl restart rsyslog`
`logger -t admin:backup starting`

That results in /var/log/admin_backup getting the log.

Notes:

- I'm running Ubunto 20.04. Platform/version-specific nuances may affect your results.
- All changes and commands have been done under `sudo -s`.
- The template doesn't need to use a Regexp. The '%property:Field' notation would be more efficient. This is to demonstrate how to use the more complex Regexp. See syntax for both [property replacer](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/property_replacer.html) operations.
- See at the end of the %syslogtag that a colon is appended and needs to be accommodated in parsing.
- Use the very helpful [regular expression test page](https://www.rsyslog.com/regex/) for Rsyslog.
- Creating new files in a folder other than /var/log presents known complications and is outside the scope of the OP request. Get this working for files in /var/log and then take on the challenge separately to get it to work with a different folder.
- Note the [action](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/basic_structure.html#outputs) uses the [dynaFile](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omfile.html#dynafile) option.
- This could also be done by putting the result of the [template into a variable](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/functions/rs-exec_template.html) with exec_template and then manipulating it further. Here is an [example page](https://www.rsyslog.com/how-to-use-set-variable-and-exec_template/).
- Rather than using a template, another way to do a regexp with Rainerscript is to use the [re_extract function](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/functions/rs-re_extract.html). Example:
  `set $.thefunction = re_extract($syslogtag,...)`